# Tensorflowjs : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow.js

This has been the most recent issue in my effort to preprocess an image I am grabbing from the DOM after the page is loaded. We have made it to where a user can load in an image and when they hit our button to identify the image, it goes through the process of preprocessing the image to be accepted to our model, prints out the Tensor object values and then when it hits the `model.predict` line, it breaks with the error in the title; `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` with this at the very bottom; `at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (main.js:39)`

However, the HTMLDivElement it is talking about is defined as I console log it for a sanity check every time I click the identify button; `User Image: <img src="data:image/png;base64,..." class="user_pic">`

This is my Tensor Object that is printed in a verbose format:

```
Tensor
  dtype: float32
  rank: 4
  shape: [1,200,200,3]
  values:
    [[[[56 , 105, 11 ],
       [53 , 101, 9  ],
       [49 , 97 , 8  ],
       ...,
       [91 , 151, 99 ],
       [92 , 152, 101],
       [91 , 151, 99 ]],

      [[56 , 102, 12 ],
       [52 , 98 , 9  ],
       [48 , 93 , 8  ],
       ...,
       [94 , 154, 103],
       [95 , 155, 104],
       [94 , 154, 103]],

      [[53 , 99 , 11 ],
       [51 , 97 , 11 ],
       [44 , 90 , 7  ],
       ...,
       [92 , 151, 103],
       [93 , 152, 104],
       [94 , 153, 105]],

      ...
      [[21 , 61 , 8  ],
       [21 , 61 , 8  ],
       [21 , 61 , 8  ],
       ...,
       [28 , 88 , 1  ],
       [36 , 93 , 4  ],
       [44 , 99 , 9  ]],

      [[22 , 62 , 9  ],
       [22 , 62 , 9  ],
       [22 , 62 , 9  ],
       ...,
       [29 , 92 , 3  ],
       [29 , 89 , 1  ],
       [40 , 98 , 7  ]],

      [[22 , 62 , 10 ],
       [22 , 62 , 10 ],
       [22 , 62 , 10 ],
       ...,
       [32 , 97 , 7  ],
       [30 , 92 , 3  ],
       [34 , 94 , 4  ]]]]
```

The other weird part, and this is something I have noticed in other tutorials and it works, is that when I process my tensor image to be in an acceptable format, I assign it to a variable but when that variable is later called upon, it is `undefined`

Full Error Below:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Fm (tfjs@latest:2)
    at e.predict (tfjs@latest:2)
    at e.predict (tfjs@latest:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (main.js:39)
```

My Code Below

```
let identify = document.querySelector('.identify')
if (identify) {
    identify.addEventListener('click', async function () {
        event.preventDefault()

        // Just a promise but is the model I need. Checked the layers and it matches up
        const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('model_json')
        console.log('This is your model: ', model)

        let user_pic = document.querySelector('.user_pic')
        console.log('User Image: ', user_pic)

        // Preprocessing is done here as it wasn't working when I saved it to a variable
        prediction = model.predict(
            tf.browser.fromPixels(user_pic).cast('float32').expandDims().print(true), { batchSize: 4 })

        console.log('This is your model: ', model, 'This is your prediction: ', prediction)
    })
```

I am curious if others have ran into this issue and understand how to possibly fix it. I am fresh to Tensorflow.js and what I have been able to find isn't exactly what I need. If anyone can help, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are passing to `model.predict` what is returned by `print` instead of the tensor itself

```
prediction = model.predict(
    tf.browser.fromPixels(user_pic).cast('float32').expandDims())
```